# I want my android application to be only run in portrait mode?

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I want my android application to be only run in portrait mode?
How can I do that?

Answer (score 899, accepted):

In the manifest, set this for all your activities:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

Let me explain:

- With `android:configChanges="orientation"` you tell Android that you will be responsible of the changes of orientation.
- `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` you set the default orientation mode.

Comment: Wouldn't be great If we could set a "global" orientation for ALL activities in the Application? Looks like we have no option but copy/paste the "portrait" attribute on every activity...

Comment: It's enough to set `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`

Comment: @EduardoCoelho you can actually make a base class `PortraitActivity` and in onCreate call `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)` All activities extending this won't rotate

Comment: @Twinone: How about when different activities want to inherit from different subclasses of `Activity`, like one activity extends from `ListActivity` while others extend simply from `Activity`?

Comment: @RestInPeace Yeah, good point. But that's not my idea being wrong, that's just Java not supporting multiple inheritance :)

Comment: @Till wouldn't be best practices to also set the configChanges?

Comment: how about that add this setting to app's theme?

Comment: Note that `android:screenOrientation` is ignored in multi-window mode https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#screen

Comment: `tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity"` - Add this to disable warning message in Manafest.xml.

Answer (score 71):

In Android Manifest File, put attribute for your `<activity>` that `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`

Comment: let me to add: from Android Sudio 3.6 need to use android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" or android:screenOrientation="unspecified".  

fullSensor Means either you have ON the "Rotate off" or not it will change the orientation based on you move the phone.  

unspecified Means if you have ON the Rotate off then it will stay only in that orientation and if not then it will change the orientation based on you move the phone.

Answer (score 28):

There are two ways,

1. Add `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` for each Activity in Manifest File
2. Add `this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);` in each java file.

Comment: The second option has the horrible side effect that it will restart your activity when started in in Portrait.

Answer (score 15):

in the manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

or : in the MainActivity

```
@SuppressLint("SourceLockedOrientationActivity")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Comment: I get `app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml; lineNumber: 20; columnNumber: 50; The prefix "tools" for attribute "tools:ignore" associated with an element type "activity" is not bound.`. Adding `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` in the root element solves the problem

Answer (score 4):

Old post I know. In order to run your app always in portrait mode even when orientation may be or is swapped etc (for example on tablets) I designed this function that is used to set the device in the right orientation without the need to know how the portrait and landscape features are organised on the device.

```
   private void initActivityScreenOrientPortrait()
    {
        // Avoid screen rotations (use the manifests android:screenOrientation setting)
        // Set this to nosensor or potrait

        // Set window fullscreen
        this.activity.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        this.activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

         // Test if it is VISUAL in portrait mode by simply checking it's size
        boolean bIsVisualPortrait = ( metrics.heightPixels >= metrics.widthPixels ); 

        if( !bIsVisualPortrait )
        { 
            // Swap the orientation to match the VISUAL portrait mode
            if( this.activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT )
             { this.activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); }
            else { this.activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT ); }
        }
        else { this.activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR); }

    }
```

Works like a charm!

NOTICE: 
Change `this.activity` by your activity or add it to the main activity and remove `this.activity` ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Alternative solution is to set activity's orientation using `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks`.

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.app.Application
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo
import android.os.Bundle

class App : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(object : ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

            override fun onActivityCreated(activity: Activity, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                activity.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT
            }

            override fun onActivityStarted(activity: Activity) {}
            override fun onActivityResumed(activity: Activity) {}
            override fun onActivityPaused(activity: Activity) {}
            override fun onActivityStopped(activity: Activity) {}
            override fun onActivitySaveInstanceState(activity: Activity, savedInstanceState: Bundle) {}
            override fun onActivityDestroyed(activity: Activity) {}
        })
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (if SDK 23 & above)

Add your `AndroidManifest.xlm`;

```
    <activity android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="locked"/>
```

like this.

Answer (score 1):

in `new SDk` of android `(24 and above)` you can use in `Manifest.xml` in `activity` tag as you want:

```
<activity
            android:name=".feature.main.MainActivity"
            ********* android:screenOrientation="locked" ******
            android:configChanges="uiMode"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:exported="true">
```

and it work!

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct. However, if you happen to be doing cross-platform development in C# using Uno Platform the Activity configuration is defined in an Activity attribute in the class. I'd expect this is the same if you're doing Xamarin or Xamarin Forms development.

Set:
ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait
in the attribute parameters.

Here's an example within my MainActivity.cs class-level attribute:

```
[Activity(MainLauncher = true,
        ConfigurationChanges = global::Uno.UI.ActivityHelper.AllConfigChanges,
        WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustPan | SoftInput.StateHidden,
        ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public class MainActivity : Windows.UI.Xaml.ApplicationActivity { }
```

#unoplatform #xamarin #csharp #windows #crossplatform

Answer (score -6):

I use

```
 android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
```

It is helpful if you do not want to support up side down portrait mode.

Comment: if this does what I think it does, it doesn't really force the screen to portrait, which you might want to do.

Comment: why don't you just remove this comment ! it doesn't make sense

Comment: In Android Manifest File just add  attribute for your <activity> that android:screenOrientation="portrait"

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is helpful for me.