# How can we set in application run only vertically not horizontally?

Tags: android, android-layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I want my android application to be only run in portrait mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723823/i-want-my-android-application-to-be-only-run-in-portrait-mode)

I want to set the database for run only vertically not in horizontally so what changes in application ?

Comment: do you want to run the app in only portrait mode ?

Comment: You do not need to personally thank every single person who answers your question, as it's considered noise and it's generally implied anyway. If you find a best answer, click the checkmark to mark it accepted.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify in your activity in manifest.xml how you want it to work

e.g

```
<activity
android:screenOrientation="landscape"> //for landscape ie horizontal
```

and

```
<activity
android:screenOrientation="portrait"> //for portrait ie vertical
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make your application in force portrait mode you can to do by adding this in the manifest file :

```
<activity android:name=".activityName" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too vague.

To use your application only vertically (portrait) mode, then following changes you have to do in manifest file

`<activity android:name=".YourActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">`

This will allow your activity to run in vertical mode (portrait mode) only and its activity configuration will not be changed even if you change device orientation.

Answer (score 0):

You do this in the AndroidManifest.xml file on the activity. Take a look at the [Activity element documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html).

```
<activity android:name=".MyCustomActivity"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
[...]
```

Programmatically you can do this in your activity as follows:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
```