# How to set app to be portrait only?

Tags: android, landscape, portrait

The only thing I can find is to use this:

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

but it stays as normal. My manifest:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As seen in the question:
[I want my android application to be only run in portrait mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723823/i-want-my-android-application-to-be-only-run-in-portrait-mode)

You should set the `configChanges` and `screenOrientation` flags for every activity, and not at the root of your manifest.

So it should look like this:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
  android:configChanges="orientation"
  android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `android:screenOrientation` must be in `<activity>` block. Also `android:configChanges` is not applicable to `<application>` but `<activity>` too.