# Prevent rotation for entire application android

Tags: android, configuration

I am now working on an android application, that is just gonna be for demo purposes. So during the development of the project, we didn't focus a lot on the orientation changes to the application. Whenever there is an orientation change, the application crashes. It is now too late to maintain the data for each activity or fragment.

So my question is, is there a way to set the orientation to potrait throughout the application. Even if the user rotates the phone, can we maintain the state to be potrait?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745797/how-to-set-entire-application-in-portrait-mode-only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Java:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle 
savedInstanceState){ 

setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

From XML:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Answer (score 2):

TL;TR: add this to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
android:configChanges="orientation"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

You can checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723823/i-want-my-android-application-to-be-only-run-in-portrait-mode) answer as well.